# How to mutate a new column with the extracted numeric values from another column in the same table in a remote PostgreSQL Database using R

Tags: r, postgresql, dplyr

I am new to R and I need to find a way to do the following: I have access to a huge remote PostgreSQL database. In this database,

- I have a table called `occurrence` and this table has a column called `uri`.
- It contains a list of URI (links to a webpage). Each entry in this column have this format: `abc://abc- def-ghi-abc/12345`.
- The only thing that changes in the column is the number 12345, the text part (the URI) stays the same throughout the column.

My question is, how can I manage to create(mutate) a new column in the same table, and this new column will be named uri_id and MUST contain ONLY the numeric part extracted from the above mentioned `uri` column.

Example:

```
|id|sub_id|uri||
|---|---|---|---|
|3654|5741|abc://abc- def-ghi-abc/12345|
|9784|5742|abc://abc- def-ghi-abc/45789|
|9751|5743|abc://abc- def-ghi-abc/97856|
|9794|5746|abc://abc- def-ghi-abc/69785|
|||||
```

Results should look like this:

```
|id|sub_id|uri|uri_id|
|---|---|---|---|
|3654|5741|abc://abc-de-fgh.abc/12345|12345|
|9784|5742|abc://abc-de-fgh.abc/45789|45789|
|9751|5743|abc://abc-de-fgh.abc/97856|97856|
|9794|5746|abc://abc-de-fgh.abc/69785|69785|
```

First I defined the table that contains this column:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dbplyr)

occurrence <- tbl(db_name, in_schema("metadata", "occurrence"))
print(occurrence)
```

returns the table normally. Then I tried this

```
str_replace(occurrence$uri, "abc://abc- def-ghi-abc/", "")
```

it returned `character (0)`. Printing it or exporting it would give `NULL` and an empty table. I also tried this:

```
uri_id <- mutate(uri_id = as.numeric(str_extract(occurrence$uri, "[0-9]+")))
```

it returned this error:

> Error in UseMethod("mutate") : no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"

I tried to just substitute text elements like this:

```
uri_id <- mutate(uri_id = as.numeric(gsub(".*?([0-9]+).*", "\\1", occurrence$uri)))
print(uri_id)
```

it returned the same error!
I tried with `extract`  and `extract_`:

```
occurrence$uri %>% extract_(occurrence$uri, "abc://abc- def-ghi-abc/")
```

This returned an error:

> Error in UseMethod("extract_") : no applicable method for 'extract_' applied to an object of class "NULL"

I would really appreciate your help in choosing the right way to achieve this task.

Comment: Does this work? `occurrence$uri_id <- sub('.*/', '', occurrence$uri)`

Comment: It returned :character(0)

Answer (score 0):

@AR4891, welcome to Stack Overflow! I think you are explaining the steps well so not sure about all the downvotes. But I think it will help to show us a few more things, especially a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

I think I'm right in thinking you are relying on `tidyverse` and `dbplyr`, so I added those in. I think you have to re-read the function descriptions and examples once more. Let me give you some examples:

Let's first create a sample dataset. I'm ignoring the `dbplyr` part and assuming just a tibble structure.

```
library(tidyverse)
occurrence <- tibble(
  id = c(3654, 9784, 9751, 9794),
  sub_id = c(5741, 5742, 5743, 5746),
  uri = c(
    "abc://abc- def-ghi-abc/12345",
    "abc://abc- def-ghi-abc/45789",
    "abc://abc- def-ghi-abc/97856",
    "abc://abc- def-ghi-abc/69785"
  )
)
```

- `str_replace(occurrence$uri, "abc://abc- def-ghi-abc/", "")` ---> you don't seem to be storing this anywhere.
- `uri_id <- mutate(uri_id = as.numeric(str_extract(occurrence$uri, "[0-9]+")))` ---> once within `mutate`, you don't need to reference the dataframe by `occurrence$` either.
- The above is also not the correct method to use `tidyr::extract` either.

If you want to take the `gsub` or `str_replace` approach,

```
occurrence %>%
  mutate(uri_id = gsub("abc://abc- def-ghi-abc/", "", uri))
```

If you want to take the `str_extract` with regex approach,

```
occurrence %>%
  mutate(uri_id = as.numeric(str_extract(uri, "[0-9]+")))
```

Let's see if either of these work.

Comment: Thanks alot. it also returned character (0).

Comment: I used dbGetQuery with an SQL substring code and it worked just fine. Thanks alot.